# Loop through JSON array in PHP laravel

Tags: php, json, foreach, laravel-5

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class welcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function welcome() {
        $cards = json_decode('[{
            "id": 1,
            "name ": "a",
            "class": "class1"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name ": "b",
            "class": "class2"
        }]');

        return view('welcome', compact('cards'));
    }
}
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
@foreach($cards as $card)
    <p>{{ $card->name }} </p>
    <p>{{ $card->class }} </p>
@endforeach
```

**Error message on browser**
[image]

I'm new to PHP laravel. Please help me to find proper solution for this.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you have everything ok in your code The issue is in the json variable

```
$cards = json_decode('[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "a",
    "class": "class1"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "b",
    "class": "class2"
  }]
');
```

the key "name "  has some space inside so in view you are tring to access as "name" that's why the error is coming

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
 return view('welcome')->with("cards",$cards);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: ohk i will remmeber it and thanks for the advice @FrankerZ

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, the 'cards' value being sent to the template is an array of arrays rather than an array of objects that your code snippet would produce.

The second argument to `json_decode()` is whether to convert to an associative array or not, defaulting to not.

Comment: I have also tried `true` as second argument to `json_decode()`. But doesn't goes the way as I want.

Comment: From the looks of things, the screenshot was when you passed true in, and the code is without. From what I can tell, the code should work as given in the description!

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because your json array is multidimensional, and your welcome.blade.php is calling the variables of name and class which don't exist at that level of the array.

In your welcome.blade.php, change your foreach to say:

```
@foreach($cards[0] as $card)
    <p>{{ $card->name }} </p>
    <p>{{ $card->class }} </p>
@endforeach
```

I believe that should get you back on track. Hope that helps!

Comment: When I use 
`@foreach($cards as $card)
    <p>{{ $card->id }} </p>
@endforeach`

It gives me below mentioned result:
`1
2`

So that means it looping through two times but not getting the values.